# Not understanding "or" & "==" is True when it is not

Tags: python

I'm having trouble understanding something simple:

```py
a = 1
b = 3

if a or b == 0:
    print(a,b)
else:
    print("NO")
```

I'm just not understanding "or" and "==" be True when it seems not.
    print(a,b) runs when values are 1,3 .

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, the correct way of checking will be `if a == 0 or b == 0`

```
In [1]: a = 1 
   ...: b = 3 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                           

In [2]: if a==0  or b == 0: 
   ...:     print(a,b) 
   ...: else: 
   ...:     print("NO") 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                           
NO
In [12]: a = 0                                                                                                                                                                    

In [13]: b = 0                                                                                                                                                                    

In [14]: if a==0  or b == 0: 
    ...:     print(a,b) 
    ...: else: 
    ...:     print("NO") 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          
0 0
```

When you do `if a or b==0` it evaluates it as `if 1`, which is True since 1 is interpreted as being `True` in Python, so it ends up being `if a`, hence you see `(1,3` being printed in the original question

```
In [9]: a = 1                                                                                                                                                                     

In [10]: b = 3                                                                                                                                                                    

In [11]: if a or b == 0: 
    ...:     print(a,b) 
    ...: else: 
    ...:     print("NO") 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          
1 3
```

Comment: Great, glad to help @sudo :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer if it helped you :) Also consider reading stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers